# How to render text with latex in Pydroid 3 interpreter?

Tags: python, sympy, pydroid

I am trying to generate scientific symbolic writing using sympy in Pydroid 3. I have tried using Pydroid's interpreter and also Jupyter console running IPython on Pydroid's terminal.The Interpreter is using ASCII printer and unicode. I want it to print using Latex. I have tried `init_session(use_latex=True)` but it doesn't change anything.

[Pydroid's Python Interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUl5O.png)

[Jupyter Console in Pydroid3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s45nz.png)

Comment: Does the Jupyter console in Pydroid support LaTeX? You might get better output with `use_unicode=True`.

Comment: I have tried that but it seems it's already using Unicode. Jupyter Notebook is able to use Latex but not its console running in Pydroid.